# Trying to make HTML table and populate select tag with same JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON data from which I am trying to make an HTML table as well as a dropdown also but facing issue to render table as well as the dropdown.

My JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Category name": "juce",
    "Category Data": [
      {
        "Item Code": "1234",
        "Item Name": "juce1",
        "Quantity": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Category name": "juce",
    "Category Data": [
      {
        "Item Code": "1234",
        "Item Name": "juce2",
        "Quantity": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Category name": "rice",
    "Category Data": [
      {
        "Item Code": "1234",
        "Item Name": "rice1",
        "Quantity": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Category name": "rice",
    "Category Data": [
      {
        "Item Code": "1234",
        "Item Name": "juce2",
        "Quantity": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Category name": "roti",
    "Category Data": [
      {
        "Item Code": "1234",
        "Item Name": "roti1",
        "Quantity": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Category name": "roti",
    "Category Data": [
      {
        "Item Code": "1234",
        "Item Name": "juce2",
        "Quantity": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to make a HTML table having dropdown outside it, named as Category Name.

Like in my JSON I have Category name which I want in a dropdown, and other data as in my HTML table.

When user will click any category inside the dropdown the HTML table gets populated according to that category name only.

'Quantity' this field is editable and will be entered by user

**Snippet of what I am trying:**

```js
function addTable(tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.
  var colNum = col.length; //to improve the speed
  for (var i = 0; i < colNum + 1; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    if (i >= colNum) {
      th.innerHTML = "Quantity";
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    } else {
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length + 1; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableData[i][col[j]];
      if (i > -1 && j >= colNum) {
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "center";
        quantityField.setAttribute('name', 'Quantity');
        quantityField.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'on');
        quantityField.setAttribute('value', '0');
        quantityField.setAttribute('type', 'number');
        quantityField.setAttribute('required', 'required');
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      } else {
        if (tableData[i]['Item Code'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableData[i]['Item Name'] === tableData[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (j > 1)
          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTable(tableData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="www.google.com" id="form1">
  <div class="row position-relative">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
      <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
        <option>All</option> <!-- this also i want to populate with the JSON DATA not statically,except All -->
        <option>juce</option>
        <option>rice</option>
        <option>roti</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="save">
      <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

But I am not getting the result.

I have only one JSON from which I want to do every thing to populate dropdown and filter also when user selects the 'category' populates the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this project, it might be better to break up the steps. I see a few steps:

- Create Table Header from Data Keys
- Create Table Body from Data
- Update Filter Options from Category Names (Unique)

Consider the following code.

```js
var tData = [{
    "Category name": "juce",
    "Category Data": [{
      "Item Code": "1234",
      "Item Name": "juce1",
      "Quantity": "0"
    }]
  },
  {
    "Category name": "juce",
    "Category Data": [{
      "Item Code": "1234",
      "Item Name": "juce2",
      "Quantity": "0"
    }]
  },
  {
    "Category name": "rice",
    "Category Data": [{
      "Item Code": "1234",
      "Item Name": "rice1",
      "Quantity": "0"
    }]
  },
  {
    "Category name": "rice",
    "Category Data": [{
      "Item Code": "1234",
      "Item Name": "juce2",
      "Quantity": "0"
    }]
  },
  {
    "Category name": "roti",
    "Category Data": [{
      "Item Code": "1234",
      "Item Name": "roti1",
      "Quantity": "0"
    }]
  },
  {
    "Category name": "roti",
    "Category Data": [{
      "Item Code": "1234",
      "Item Name": "juce2",
      "Quantity": "0"
    }]
  }
];

$(function() {
  function getCatNames(arr) {
    var names = [];
    $.each(arr, function(key, obj) {
      names.push(obj['Category name']);
    });
    var unique = names.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
    return unique;
  }

  function updateFilter(obj, d) {
    var catOpts = getCatNames(d);
    obj.html("");
    obj.append("<option>All</option>");
    $.each(catOpts, function(k, v) {
      $("<option>").html(v).appendTo(obj);
    });
  }

  function filterSelection(obj) {
    var s = $("#CategoryName option:selected").val();
    if (s == "All") {
      $("tbody tr", obj).show();
      return;
    }
    $("tbody tr", obj).each(function(ind, el) {
      var cat = $("td:eq(0)", el).text().trim();
      if (cat != s) {
        $(el).hide();
      } else {
        $(el).show();
      }
    });
  }

  function makeTableHead(obj, data) {
    if (obj.find("thead").length === 0) {
      $("<thead>").prependTo(obj);
    }
    var row = $("<tr>").appendTo($("thead", obj));
    $.each(data[0], function(k, v) {
      console.log(k, v);
      if (k == "Category name") {
        $("<th>", {
          class: "text-center head"
        }).html(k).appendTo(row);
      } else {
        $.each(v[0], function(j, x) {
          $("<th>", {
            class: "text-center head"
          }).html(j).appendTo(row);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  function makeTableBody(obj, data, qnty) {
    if (qnty == undefined) {
      qnty = true;
    }
    if (obj.find("tbody").length === 0) {
      $("<tbody>").appendTo(obj);
    }
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
      var row = $("<tr>", {
        class: "item-" + k
      }).appendTo($("tbody", obj));
      var n = $("<td>", {
        class: "text-center cat-name"
      }).html(v['Category name']).appendTo(row);
      $("<input>", {
        type: "hidden",
        name: "cat-name[]",
        value: v['Category name']
      }).appendTo(n);
      var itc = $("<td>", {
        class: "text-center item-code"
      }).appendTo(row);
      itc.html(v['Category Data'][0]['Item Code']);
      $("<input>", {
        type: "hidden",
        name: "item_code",
        value: v['Category Data'][0]['Item Code']
      }).appendTo(itc);
      var itn = $("<td>", {
        class: "text-center item-name"
      }).appendTo(row);
      itn.html(v['Category Data'][0]['Item Name']);
      $("<input>", {
        type: "hidden",
        name: "item_name",
        value: v['Category Data'][0]['Item Name']
      }).appendTo(itn);
      if (qnty) {
        var q = $("<td>", {
          class: "cat-qnty"
        }).appendTo(row);
        $("<input>", {
          name: "Quantity",
          autocomplete: "on",
          value: v['Category Data'][0].Quantity,
          type: "number",
          class: "dataReset"
        }).css({
          border: "none",
          "text-align": "center",
          width: "4em"
        }).appendTo(q);
      }
    });
  }

  function addTable(tableData, tbl) {
    if (tbl == undefined) {
      tbl = $("<table>", {
        id: "HourlysalesSummary"
      });
    }
    //var col = Object.keys(tableData[0]);
    //var countNum = col.length;
    makeTableHead(tbl, tableData);
    makeTableBody(tbl, tableData);
    var divContainer = $("#HourlysalesSummary").parent();
    divContainer.html(tbl);
    tbl.addClass("table table-striped table-bordered table-hover");
  }

  updateFilter($("#CategoryName"), tData);
  addTable(tData, $("#HourlysalesSummary"));

  $("#CategoryName").change(function() {
    filterSelection($("#HourlysalesSummary"));
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="www.google.com" id="form1">
  <div class="row position-relative">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h5 id="commonHeader">Category</h5>
      <select class="test" id="CategoryName" name="categoryCode">
        <option>All</option>
        <option>juce</option>
        <option>rice</option>
        <option>roti</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="w-100" id="HourlysalesSummary">
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="save"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, I have created the following functions:

- `addTable( data )`

  - `makeTableHead( object, data, quantity )`
  - `makeTableBody( object, data, quantity )`
- `updateFilter( object, data )`

  - `getCatNames( data )`
  - `filterSelection( object )`

Making use of `<thead>` and `<tbody>` can help when you have more dynamic table body content. If you make a change or load new data, you may only need to run `makeTableBody($("#HourlysalesSummary"), tData);` with the new data.

I switched a lot of your code to jQuery. I don't like to mix if possible. This also lets us use `$.each()` more which is really helpful with Array and Object data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey data is not getting filtered when user changes any dropdown,also table headers are  itemname itemcode and quantity

Comment: @viveksingh I used the example data you provided for HTML. I have updated the code with the update `filterSelection()`.

Comment: i think you are missing somthing my table header should be `Item Name` `Item Code` and `Quntity` Category Name is only to show in  dropdown,but here you are showing somthing else in table

Comment: @viveksingh updated. It was very unclear from your JSON Data structure.

Comment: @viveksingh also, for larger tables, consider using https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

You'd be wise to pick a utility library, such as Underscore or Lodash, to make array manipulation a little easier.  For this example, I used Lodash.

```
var data = []/ //enter your array of data here instead of empty array
var dataArray = []; //this will hold a collection of Category Names
for (datum of data) {
   console.log(datum);
   dataArray.push(datum["Category name"]);
}
uniqueArrayForDropdown = _.sortedUniq(dataArray); //only save unique category names
```

Now, when someone chooses a category name, you can filter your `data` object with a function like the following (here I set `rice` as static, but you would change this to be the value selected from the dropdown):

```
//this is the simple example with static data
data.filter(function(item) {return item["Category name"] === "rice";})
```

You can apply that by setting creating a function like the following, and setting a change event to execute `filterSelection()`:

```
// this is a dynamic function that reads the selected value from the
// DOM and applies the filter accordingly
function filterSelection() {
   var e = document.getElementById("CategoryName");
   var selectedCategory = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   var filteredData = data.filter(function(item) {return item["Category name"] === selectedCategory;})

   drawTable(filteredData); //you need to write the drawTable method
}
```

As long as your table logic is correct, you can have it draw the `filteredData` array; `filteredData` contains the subset of `data` objects that matched the filter criterion.

Comment: can you add some sort of snippet please.